# Is a Jew allowed to go on Facebook?

Tags: gentiles, internet

Sanhedrin 74a states that if the non-Jews are accustomed to have red shoe laces we should not have red shoe laces.

What is the extent to this rule of not copying the gentiles?

I have a few questions on this

1. What is the extent to this? For example if the gentiles make Facebook can I go on it
2. What about something that is not made for both Jews and gentiles? For example a famous habit they have done?
3. What about something that falls in category 2 (or 3) (does it matter?) but it was also done by Jews? For example Facebook?

So like I said above my question is

**What is the extent do we follow the rule of not copying the gentiles?**

See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch Siman 3 Se'if 2

Comment: Is this a general question about emulating gentiles or a specific question about Facebook? Currently, it reads like both, which could result in answers that don't address what you want.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I do not think they are both Mutually Exclusive. I am asking a general question and Facebook goes into that general question

Comment: @user6781 There could be a whole bunch of other considerations that go into "Is a Jew allowed to go on Facebook?" and conversely, many aspects of the general discussion of the parameters prohibition of emulating gentiles that would have nothing to do with the case of Facebook.

Comment: @IsaacMoses So I am asking in the aspect of my general question. So that is why I gave my general question.

Comment: @user6781, I would recommend refocusing this question under the title "How does the rule of not copying the gentiles apply to Facebook?" with everything in the question body explicitly supporting that specific question.

Comment: Didn't a Jew make Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

I just saw a Kleinman Edition of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch and it wrote in a footnote

"4. It is not forbidden to follow customs that have clearly developed for a specific benefit. For example, it is permitted for a physician to wear a doctor's coat so as to be recognize as a professional See Rama, Yoreh Deah 178"

So it seems from that, that you are not allowed to do anything that does not benefit you in anyway, but the only purpose to copy the goyim.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, when ever it comes to social media it is permissible to have and even encouraged if it is related to a mitzvah. For example, if you are sending out halachas to people through social media then go for it. If you are only using for things that are gashmius (physical) then you should not have it.

Number 2: It says one should not dress like a goy, that is what Sanhedrin is bringing out. We should dress how yiddin (Jews) dress, in a nice and proper manner. I cannot find my sources right now but I will when I have a chance.

Please let me know if this helps